# SSIS 2012 package to import excel data to database table

Tags: excel-2007, ssis-2012, data-import

I want to make a SSIS package that will load data from an excel file to a database table.

I have already made a package that completes the task, but the table needs to be recreated every time the excel data is loaded because the excel data and its column definition changes every month. If the table is not created with every execution there will be errors and my task will not be complete because excel data will be loaded under a wrong column definition.

Is there any way to dynamically drop and create the table every time?

Answer (score 0):

SSIS generates a lot of metadata behind the scenes which describe your source and destination fields and mappings. If it feels it isn't talking to the same data source/destination it will often throw a validation error and refuse to start.

To an extent you can mitigate this by setting DelayValidation to True on the connection manager properties. However this is unlikely to help in your case as your data spec genuinely is changing.

A further option to get around the tight controls on data format is to write your own custom source/transformation/destination logic in script tasks. You can write a script task to read the format of the incoming Excel file, and save those details to variables and pass them into an Execute SQL Task to create the table. Then you can write a script task to dynamically map your data to some generic intermediate columns that exist within your package. Finally you can write a script task destination to load that data into the newly created table.

Basically you're bypassing all out of the box SSIS functionality and writing your own integration solution from the ground up, but it seems you don't have much choice.